# 14.04 LTS, 32-bit, Software Updater error "Failed to download repository information: Check your internet connection"

Tags: updates

There isn't much to say about this one: when I run Software Updater, I get the above error message. That can't be good.

Interestingly, when I click on "Settings..." and then close the settings dialogue that pops up, all of a sudden Software Updater successfully finds updates and installs them.

I thought I should bring this to the attention of the Ubuntu community.

sudo apt-get update returns the following:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have screen captures, but I don't have enough reputation points to post them.

Comment: What is the question? What is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @LucasW Post screen-shot of error or out-put from terminal. It seems you have mis-understanding with Software & Updates visit : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates for fully information about sotware-updates.

Comment: bain: I edited the question to include the output of sudo apt-get update Pandya: I don't believe this is the result of a misunderstanding on my part. I have screen captures for you if you need proof of what I'm claiming, but unfortunately I can't post them at the moment because I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @underdog012 No, this does not appear to be the same error (in the link above). It's similar but not quite what I'm experiencing. Again, I wish I could post my screen caps. How do I acquire more reputation points?

Comment: @LucasW You can always upload your screen caps to an external hosting provider like imgur and link them here. A high-rep user could then embed them in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error message because [the deluge-team repository](http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages) doesn't exist. So when the Software Updater runs it can't find the repo so it gives you this error message. I looked it up for you and indeed the repository doesn't exist for Trusty.

You can look it up [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/). So either you will remove the repository or you can change the distribution. I don't know how safe though is the second solution because the software that this repository gives is for older versions of Ubuntu and installing software that exists for older versions may harm the OS.

If you still though you want to give it a try please reply and I will give you a brief guide with pictures on how to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But what do you make of the fact that when I click on the Software Updater's "Settings..." button, and then close the Settings dialogue, the Software Updater then finds new updates and successfully installs them?

Comment: The Updater just gives you a warning for a specific repository.The fact that there are updated packages from other sources(repositories) will not stop the Updater to download them and install them.Unless you mean something else which I can't understand. :)

Comment: yeah you appear to be misunderstanding me. I can't be any clearer without posting screen caps. Unfortunately I can't at the moment.

Comment: Explain again please which part I missunderstood.

Comment: Firstly, you're linking to some other problem that's vaguely similar, but unrelated as far as I can see, so I don't even know if we're on the same page to begin with. I've described the problem as clearly and concisely as I am able. Please re-read the second paragraph of the original question. I'm just wondering why, after reporting that I should check my internet connection (which is fine, btw), the Software Updater then successfully installs updates after I click settings and close the settings dialogue? Looks like a software bug to me. But I'm an Ubuntu noob.

Comment: So everytime you hit the Settings button the Software Updater says that it found new updates and installed them?Or you get the error and then it says that your computer is up to date.Try to do the same without opening the Settings and tell me if this happens again.